# Flexbox align-items stretch issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I have a 2 column container. On the left side, there is an image. On the right side, I have 2 `<p>` elements. I want to position one `<p>` element at the top, the other at the bottom of the container.

I tried to use flexblox, with `align-items` to stretch, but that doesn't work. Although `flex-start` and `flex-end` does work.

Is this even possible with flexbox?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.element-box {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature">
  </div>
  <div class="element-box">
    <p>Should be on Top</p>
    <p>Should be on Bottom</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make your `element-box` a *column* `flexbox` and give `justify-content: space-between`. Also remove `height: 100%` from it.

See demo below:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.element-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature">
  </div>
  <div class="element-box">
    <p>Should be on Top</p>
    <p>Should be on Bottom</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need flex for second container too where you are having you `<p>` elements, please look at css below it'll help you:

```
.element-box {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: space-between;
flex-grow: 1;
}
```